# JavaFX TreeView edit item

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I am trying to edit a `TreeView` item, below is my code,

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.*;

public class TreeViewSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    TreeView<Object> tree;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");

        TreeItem<Object> rootItem = new TreeItem<Object>("Tree");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            TreeItem<Object> item = new TreeItem<Object>("Item" + i);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }

        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem renameItem = new MenuItem("Rename");
        menu.getItems().add(renameItem);

        tree = new TreeView<Object>(rootItem);
        tree.setContextMenu(menu);
        tree.setEditable(true);

        tree.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Object>, TreeCell<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<Object> call(TreeView<Object> p) {
                return new TextFieldTreeCell<Object>();
            }
        });
        renameItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                tree.edit(tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            }
        });

        tree.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TreeView.EditEvent<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TreeView.EditEvent<Object> event) {
                System.out.println("Commit Value");
            }
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

While editing and commit the value,

If the `TreeView` and `TreeItem` generic types are `String` i have used 
`return new TextFieldTreeCell<String>(new DefaultStringConverter());`

When I use `Object` , i am not sure how to use **String converter** which leads to ,

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Attempting to convert text input into Object, but provided StringConverter is null. Be sure to set a StringConverter in your cell factory.
```

How can i mitigate this exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Displaying `Object` instances in a `TreeView` does not really make sense as they do not store any information to display.

Practically, the following `StringConverter` helps you to remove the error:

```
tree.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Object>, TreeCell<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public TreeCell<Object> call(TreeView<Object> p) {
        return new TextFieldTreeCell<Object>(new StringConverter<Object>(){

            @Override
            public String toString(Object object) {
                return object.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Object fromString(String string) {
                return new Object();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What it does: It defines a `StringConverter` which will return a new `Object` instance **from any** string typed into the `TextField` on commit (as the `Object` does not store any information to identify, this is the best you can have) and will display the `String` got from the `toString()` method of the `Object` instance.

**But:** You should provide a data model for the `TreeView` to display, which is capable to store at least the textual data that could be displayed.

I have updated your code to create an **example** of a `TreeView` backed by a really simple data model:

It defines the data model for the tree (`Item` class) which class has one single property to the the name of the item. The generic parameter of the `TreeView` is set to this `Item` class, therefore the `TreeView` is capable to display `Item` instances.

As you can see I have defined a `StringConverter` also, which now makes much more sense: the `fromString` method is executed when the typed text is commited, in this case the method will return a new `Item` instance, that has its name set to the input String. The `toString` method is needed to specify, how to textually display an `Item` instance. In our case we will return the name of the particular instance.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.*;

public class TreeViewSample2 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    TreeView<Item> tree;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");

        TreeItem<Item> rootItem = new TreeItem<Item>(new Item("Root"));


        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            TreeItem<Item> item = new TreeItem<Item>(new Item("Item"+i));
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }

        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem renameItem = new MenuItem("Rename");
        menu.getItems().add(renameItem);

        tree = new TreeView<Item>(rootItem);
        tree.setContextMenu(menu);
        tree.setEditable(true);

        tree.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Item>, TreeCell<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<Item> call(TreeView<Item> p) {
                return new TextFieldTreeCell<Item>(new StringConverter<Item>(){

                    @Override
                    public String toString(Item object) {
                        return object.getName();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Item fromString(String string) {
                        return new Item(string);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        renameItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                tree.edit(tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            }
        });

        tree.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TreeView.EditEvent<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TreeView.EditEvent<Item> event) {
                System.out.println("Commit Value");
            }
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class Item {
    private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public final String getName() { return nameProperty().get();}
    public final void setName(String newName) { nameProperty().set(newName);}

    public Item(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: beware: the commitHandler is installed incorrectly (assuming the edited value should be saved) - setOnXX replaces the default handler which saves the edited value, so you loose the saving part (please see the api doc). That said: until fx19, you get away with it because a) treeView [has no default handler](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187473) and b) TreeCell [commit incorrectly jumps in](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187309) and writes the data itself